# Blocked:mixed content on Laravel post request when optional route parameter is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, mixed-content, inertiajs

I have a route defined as follows

```
Route::post('s3/create/directory/{path?}', [S3Controller::class, 'createDirectory'])
            ->name('s3.create.directory')
            ->where('path', '.*');
```

It works fine when posting to it, except when the `path` value is an empty string, then I get a `blocked:mixed-content` from Chrome.

I have triple checked, and there are no HTTP requests on the page and because I am using InertiaJS, it actually comes from the same page. The only difference is that the `path` value is an empty string.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This happens because in where() you expect path not to be null, my suggestion is to avoid doing this in the route and try to make a recourse where you can put path to be nullable and path.* to be required

Comment: That's weird, because the following works fine with an empty path: `Route::get('s3/browse/{path?}', [S3Controller::class, 'index'])->name('s3.browse')->where('path', '.*');`
I don't see why this would behave differently with `POST`

Comment: Did you find a fix ? I have the same problem on production where my inertia request wants to load over http (while everything is https)

Comment: @Joeri No, sorry. It turns out the client didn't want the ability to add directories in the root, so the problem just went away. I'd still love to hear the solution though.

Comment: @surya i found out you can 'force' requests to be over https. Don't remember what exactly i changed but that fixed it for me.